# Angular and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am learning angular, and I am using ASP.NET MVC5. I am unable to return data from mvc controller via angular.

The route should be localhost/Product/Test, but when angular get method is calling it the url is locahost/Product/Product/Test. Any help is appreacited.

Is the approach I have taken correct also? Because I have seen many tutorials where they show how to return a view only. But cannot seem to find how to return a view and data.

**Screenshot**
[image: Screen Shot]

**MVC controller**

```
public ActionResult Test()
        {
            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            var db = new HotStuffPizzaContext();

            var result = (from p in db.Products
                          select p)
                          .Where(x => x.ProductID != 0)
                          .Select(a => new
                          {
                              ProductID = a.ProductID,
                              Description = a.Description
                          });
            return View("~/Views/Product/_Test.cshtml", result);
}
```

**Angular app**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/Test', {
        url: '/Product',
        templateUrl: '../../Views/Product/_Test.cshtml',
        controller: 'testCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

}]);

myApp.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
      $http.get('Product/Test').success(function (data) {
          $scope.products = data;
      });
  }]);
```

**Partial View**

```
<html data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/App/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div>
        <table class="table table-striped">

            <tr data-ng-repeat="p in products">
                <th>id</th>
                <th>description</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>{{p.productid}}</td>
                <td>{{p.description}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Index View**

```
<h1>INDEX VIEW</h1>
<div data-ng-view=""></div>

<a href="/Product/Test">Test</a>

<script src="../../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/App/app.js"></script>
```

**UPDATE**[image: JSON RESULT]

Comment: Try to take /Product out of the link in your Index View.

Comment: What is your controller name ? (the class that contains your Test action.

Comment: @RickestRick I get the following Server Error in '/' Application. And URL is http://localhost:14634/Test

Comment: @CodeNotFound Product Controller

Comment: Which is the part that failed into you js file ?

Comment: If you change anything here the url is altered   $http.get('Product/Test').success(function (data) {

Comment: First replace "Product/Test" with "/Product/Test" notice the "/" at the beginning.

Comment: in the contoller or the config? @CodeNotFound

Comment: In  $http.get('Product/Test').

Comment: that has worked, but it is only returning html and not the model? if you see my return View("",model). Now how can i get json, do I do another call? I am confused on this aspect

Comment: I know :D I just answered below.

Comment: haha beat me to my question, let me try this out. Because I did try returning json like how you have mentioned but without the .ToList(); and that simply shows a page with json result.

Answer (score 2):

First replace **"Product/Test"** with **"/Product/Test"** notice the "/" at the beginning

Your action will are not implemnted to return a json data but a View (which will be plain HTML) sent to your Angular App.

You must return a Json data in your Test action. Replace the following line:

```
return View("~/Views/Product/_Test.cshtml");
```

by this line:

```
return Json(result.ToList());
```

You might need to allow `GET` method with AJAX request then use:

```
return Json(result.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Don't forget to add `[GET]` attribute to your Test action.

You must look at using ASP.Net Web API instead of ASP.Net MVC.

**Update 1: Based on the comment below this answer :**

Replace linq query by renaming your anonymous type correctly like this :

```
var result = (from p in db.Products
               select p)
               .Where(x => x.ProductID != 0)
               .Select(a => new
                {
                    productid = a.ProductID,
                    description = a.Description
                });
```

Notice that there is no upper case into anonymous type properties. You must use it like this because your AngularJS App need it:

```
<tr>
     <td>{{p.productid}}</td>
     <td>{{p.description}}</td>
</tr>
```

**Update 2: You need to have two actions**

- One that return your view **Test**
- another one to get your data **TestData**

Your `Test` will look like this:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
     return View("~/Views/Product/_Test.cshtml");
}
```

Your `TestData` liek this:

```
public ActionResult TestData()
{
        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        var db = new HotStuffPizzaContext();

        var result = (from p in db.Products
                      select p)
                      .Where(x => x.ProductID != 0)
                      .Select(a => new
                      {
                          productid= a.ProductID,
                          description = a.Description
                      });
        return Json(result.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Finally replace the url of `$http.get('Product/Test')` with `$http.get('/Product/TestData')`.

Comment: I just tried this, and it takes me to a result of json [{"ProductID":1,"Description":"Margarita"},{"ProductID":2,"Description":"Pepperoni"},{"ProductID":3,"Description":"Burger"}]

Comment: it did not effect, still get the same result, I have updated the question and included a screen shot

Comment: It doesn't work, it just returns what is in my screen shot. in the debugger i cannot see any scripts loaded into the page

Comment: no, by clicking the href in Index view. The Product Controller is now doing return Json(result.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); (this is what is causing to do this)

Comment: I have tried this, and still get the same result. :z

Comment: It still has the same result...:(

Comment: I am using v1.5.0, will try this.

Comment: Nothing happens with this change, only the url changed.http://localhost:14634/Product#Product/Test

Comment: your route prodivder are accepting only /Test. 
Then replace "#Product/Test" with "#Test" :D

Comment: yep <a href="#Test">Test</a>

Comment: I think the primary issue of your question is resolved. You can create a new thread for this.

Anyway => remove  url: '/Product', that you put into your routing provider.

Comment: yes thanks for all your help! it seems we are doing all the steps correctly but missing something in the middle!